# Pandas - Converting column of type float to date time

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a Dataframe with 2 columns that are float64 objects. I am trying to convert these to dates.

```
col1, col2
43835.0, 0.145833
43835.0, 0.166667
```

Expected output:

```
col1, col2
05/01/2020,3:30:00 AM
05/01/2020, 4:00:00 AM
```

When I try `pd.to_datetime(df['col1'])` it convert the values to `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043835` and `1970-01-01` respectively

Comment: @jezrael, thanks for sharing. It did help for `col1` but not for `col2`

Comment: Maybe stupd idea, is possible `sum` both columns before?

Comment: @jezrael actually `col2` is the time component whereas `col1` is the date component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is possible convert to datetimes fist column and second to timedeltas:

```
df['col1'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['col1'], unit='d') + pd.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
df['col2'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['col2'], unit='d').dt.floor('S')
print (df)
        col1     col2
0 2020-01-05 03:29:59
1 2020-01-05 04:00:00
```

One idea for custom dates and times, but becuase precision output is a bit different:

```
s = df['col1'] + df['col2']
dates = pd.to_timedelta(s, unit='d').add(pd.datetime(1899, 12, 30)).dt.floor('S')

df['col1'] = dates.dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df['col2'] = dates.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S %p')
print (df)
         col1         col2
0  05/01/2020  03:29:59 AM
1  05/01/2020  04:00:00 AM
```